# string is valid double or not

Tags: iphone

class or instance method for checking string is valid integer?

Comment: Do you want doubles or integers?

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSScanner for that. NSString itself also has -doubleValue and -intValue methods.

Comment: I'd say that NSScanner would be the preferred way, as -scanDouble: returns YES or NO depending on whether the string has a valid floating point number within it or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at the ENTIRE string, rather than just a portion, you could just use -intValue or -doubleValue. If it returns non-zero, it's valid.

Comment: But what if the string is actually "0" or "0.0"?  Admittedly, checking for a non-zero number can be good enough for many cases.